# Why DataFrame.drop() does not work for column way (axis = 1)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I generate a dataframe and try to drop the second column, but the code only work for the row (`axis = 0`) not for the column (`axis = 1`), wondering why?

```
data1 ={"Name":pd.Series(['Sam','Paul','Jim']), 
      "Score1":pd.Series([100, 90, 85]), 
      "Score2":pd.Series([80, 85, 90])}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

df1.drop(1, axis = 1, inplace = True)
print(df1)
```

This keeps generating an error message that `KeyError: '[1] not found in axis`

Comment: that first argument is for a column name, not a column index

Comment: `df1 = df1.drop(columns=["Score1"])`

Comment: i think this link can help you to better understand https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-delete-rows-columns-from-dataframe-using-pandas-drop/#:~:text=Pandas%20provide%20data%20analysts%20a,column%20name%20using%20this%20method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `axis=0`, the first argument is the `index` to remove. `index` as in the name ("label" in pandas terminology) of the index, not the index of the row.

Similarly, when `axis=1` the first argument is the name of the column to remove, not the index of the column.

```
df1.drop(1, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

should be

```
df1.drop('Score1', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Alternatively, use the more explicit way using the `columns` argument:

```
df1.drop(columns='Score1', inplace=True)
```

All this is covered in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

> labels, single label or list-like Index or column labels to drop.
>
> axis, {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0 Whether to drop labels
> from the index (0 or ‘index’) or columns (1 or ‘columns’).
>
> index, single label or list-like Alternative to specifying axis (labels,
> axis=0 is equivalent to index=labels).
>
> columns, single label or list-like Alternative to specifying axis
> (labels, axis=1 is equivalent to columns=labels).